# Mix audio/video of different lengths with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to mix video from `video.mp4` (1 minute duration) and audio from `audio.mp3` (10 minute duration) into one output file with a duration of 1 minute. The audio from `audio.mp3` should be from the 4 min - 5 min position. How can I do this with `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## If `video.mp4` has no audio

You can use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:04:00 -i audio.mp3 -c copy -shortest output.mkv
```

- The audio will be from the 4 minute position (`-ss 00:04:00`) as requested in the question.
- This example will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) the video and audio–no re-encoding will happen.

## If `video.mp4` has audio

You will have to add the `-map` option as described here: [FFmpeg mux video and audio (from another video) - mapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12943003/1109017).

## If the audio is shorter than the video

Add the [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) filter to add silent padding:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:04:00 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -af apad -shortest output.mkv
```

Note that filtering requires re-encoding, so the audio will be re-encoded in this example.

Comment: Thanks. I do not ask at superuser, because I find, that at stackoverflow many questions ask as my issue. Now understood, it' wrong.

Comment: LordNeckbeard, I think you mistakes. Because after execute video reduced. I try set start time 30s and see, that output video is 30s, not 1 min

Comment: LordNeckbeard, sorry. I'm wrong. Before I used do not last ffmpeg version. Now, all works. Again thanks for script

Comment: How would you go about adding a video from a certain time to its end, when the video is longer? Meaning there will be a silent part at the end of the video

Comment: `-shortest` results in the encoding ending when the shorter stream ends but lets say I have a video of 10 minutes, and an audio of 3 minutes, I want the first 3 minutes of the video to play the audio, and the rest to be silent, how should I go bout that ?

Comment: @bluesummers I understand now. Easiest method is to use the apad filter. See updated answer.