# FFMPEG mux video and audio from two videos

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I was trying the same thing as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938581/ffmpeg-mux-video-and-audio-from-another-video-mapping-issue/47844450#47844450) with two mkv, with the video from the first file and all the audio tracks and subtitles from the second file:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -i 2.mkv -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 1:s -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -shortest out.mkv
```

but it's not working, in output I have a file whith broken audio track, if I run it with VLC it seems ok until I skip forward or change audio track, everything I do will stop executing the audio track.

If I run VLC from terminal for some verbosity I obtain:

```
core decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
```

Any idea?

-------Edit-------------------------------

I think the problem was with the subs, if I remove the subs everything works good. Is it possible that the "-shortest" option broke something because of the length of the subs?

Comment: Without the log/console output from the `ffmpeg` command we can only make guesses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix `-map` for each mapping. Use:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -i 2.mkv -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 1:s -c copy -shortest out.mkv
```

<sub>Although I'm guessing you may have just typed it incorrectly in your question so this may not be the solution to your actual issue.</sub>