# extract subtitle from mkv file

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv

i have an mk file containing 2 subtitles, i want to extract the first:

```
Stream #0:2(ger): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 1920x1080 (default) (forced)
    Metadata:
      title           : Deutsch (Forced)
      BPS-eng         : 261
      DURATION-eng    : 02:12:34.273000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 75
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 260312
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v24.0.0 ('Beyond The Pale') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-06-16 14:56:38
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
```

i tried ffmpeg `-i Movie.mkv -map 0:s:0 subs.srt` but i got the following error

```
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: dvd_subtitle is image based. srt is text based. ffmpeg can't convert them. There is the [ocr filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ocr), but I don't think it will be very practical in this case.

Comment: i don't understand much about this. What i actually want is to copy that subtitle to another movie, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, use the `-map` option. See [FFMPEG mux video and audio (from another video)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938581/ffmpeg-mux-video-and-audio-from-another-video-mapping-issue/12943003#12943003). Example:  `ffmpeg -i MovieWithSubs.mkv -i AnotherMovie.mkv -map 1 -map 0:s:0 -c copy output.mkv`

Comment: ok thank you. One more question: what if the movie with subtitles is a normal 2d and the movie i want to add them to, is side-to-side 3D? How can i add them such that they don't get ditorted?

Comment: Have you tried it? Your player may be smart enough for it to just work. Or at least with text based subtitles (or "ASS" subtitles specifically).

Comment: yes i have tried it, but since it's not the player(vlc btw) creating the 3d effect of the images, but the beamer, it doesn't work that way

Comment: I don't have an answer. I have no experience with 3D and I don't have any way to try it myself. I recommend asking it as a new question at [su] or [video.se].