# FFmpeg — segmentation fault when trying to replace audio

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have exactly this scenario: [FFMPEG mux video and audio (from another video) - mapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12938581/12141355). I want to mux the video stream from one file and the audio stream from another.

[image]

I have renamed the files accordingly and, when trying to follow [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12943003/12141355)

```
ffmpeg -i input_0.mp4 -i input_1.mp4 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:1 -shortest out.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input_0.mp4 -i input_1.mp4 -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest out.mp4
```

I get

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped).
```

The same happens when I follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1137613/1039759) under [ffmpeg - replace audio in video](https://superuser.com/q/1137612/1039759), which tries to mux the audio (as a separate file) with the video stream.

```
ffmpeg -i input_0.mp4 -i a.aac -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 new.mp4
```

What can I do?

---

In reply to comment:

```
ffmpeg -i input_0.mp4 -i input_1.mp4 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:1 -shortest out.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.2.1-0york0~18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0york0~18.04.1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

---

Looking at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/85300/1039759) under [FFMPEG Segfault Solutions](https://superuser.com/q/85096/1039759):

```
~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

~$ ldd /usr/bin/ffmpeg | grep x264
    libx264.so.155 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.155 (0x00007f497f5f9000)
    libx264.so.152 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.152 (0x00007f496e837000)

~$ cat /usr/include/x264.h | grep X264_BUILD
cat: /usr/include/x264.h: No such file or directory
```

but in Synaptic I see this:

[image: Synaptic libx264]

Comment: Have a look at - https://superuser.com/questions/85096/ffmpeg-segfault-solutions

Comment: @llogan - added what I see in terminal

Comment: @llogan - as far as I remember I simply installed it with `apt`from Ubuntu/Mint repos. I have added some info in relation with the answer you linked. I'll try to use other ffmpeg and report back.

Comment: @llogan - For the moment I have removed the installed ffmpeg and using the static  johnvansickle package the first 2 commands give another error, but the last command seems to work.

Comment: @llogan - thanks for posting your answer. I was about to post one only if you did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the ffmpeg package from the PPA you are using ([jonathonf](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg-4) probably).

What you can try:

- This package is outdated compared to what is currently available in that PPA, so you can try updating and see if that fixes the problem: `sudo apt update`.
- [Remove the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/310/59378) and install the ffmpeg package from the official Ubuntu repository, or from [johnvansickle.com](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (see install [FAQ](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/)), or follow a [step-by-step guide to compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) it yourself, or use snap.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i v.mp4 -i a.wav -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 new.mp4` worked with the static  johnvansickle version. I'll follow your advice above to check the other commands that gave error again, and then I'll report here to complete your answer.

Comment: The non-working version (jonathonf, but the ppa was already removed at some point) was ffmpeg version 4.2.1. Installing the ubuntu version I get version 3.4.6 — *that has exactly the same problem as the 4.2.1*. The successful static version is **4.2.2**. I don't know if I need to compile the last version or keep the outdated ubuntu version.

Comment: @cipricus So 3.4.6 also seg faults?

Comment: `ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1` gives the same errors as 4.2.1 (jonathonf) with the commands listed in my question here (it works otherwise). But maybe that is another issue, given that it also shows me `WARNING: library configuration mismatch`. On the other hand, for the purpose of [this](https://superuser.com/q/982342/1039759) (`ffmpeg  -i "in.mp4" -itsoffset 0.20 -i "in.mp4" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy "out.mp4"`), the same 3.4.6 works ok.

Comment: I cannot look further into this because I don't have anymore the original files, they  were too big on my laptop, I only have the synced final version. Do you need those results? I could try experimenting with what I have.

Comment: @cipricus No. I'm guessing the error was `Invalid input file index` or `Stream map '0:1' matches no streams` or similar due to wrong map index numbers (the second example in your question is less prone to that mistake).

Comment: Note that if you have the version from the ubuntu repository installed and it gives you a segfault, installing it from the ppa can help.