# What are the required domains to know to make a video editor application for android ? with features like Speed, Rotation, Transition, Trim, Split

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-editing

I wanted to make a Video Editor application for Android. But I am not sure whether only FFMPEG is enough or not. In this application I want to add features like Trim, Split, Filter, Speed, Rotation, Transition, Text, Music etc. I think only FFMPEG is not enough, some other Library or Domain I have to know. Can any one help on this ?

Comment: ffmpeg is not a video editor, but it can do all of those features.

Comment: @llogan, do u think "Transition" is also possible with FFMPEG in Android App ?

Comment: Yes, with the xfade filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ffmpeg` can do all of these:

- Trim: `-ss` and/or `-t`/`-to` options. trim and atrim filters.
- Split: same as trim
- Filter: See [FFmpeg Filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html).
- Speed: setpts, atempo, rubberband filters
- Rotation: rotate, transpose, hflip, vflip filters. `-metadata rotate` option. Also see [How to rotate a video with FFmpeg?](https://superuser.com/a/578329/)
- Transition: [xfade](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade) filter
- Text: drawtext and subtitles filters. Also see [Text on video ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624103/).
- Music: add as input file and mux. amerge and amix filters. Also see [How to overlay/downmix two audio files using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528482/), [FFMPEG mux video and audio (from another file)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12943003/)

Comment: @Ilogan, thank you. After covering all those areas of FFMPEG, do u think I also need to have knowledge on Android's  MediaCodec or VideoCodec ?

Comment: @Mahfuz Probably, if it can do any of the above you should prefer MediaCodec over ffmpeg as it may be faster. But I have no experience with that. ffmpeg can use MediaCodec for decoding, but not yet for encoding.