# How map_channel works in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I need to extract channels from 5.1 audios. These audio tracks are contained in a MKV file. Structure of "movie.mkv" file is like this:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'movie.mkv':
  Duration: 00:40:38.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 21128 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2(ger): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: subrip
```

But the syntax is very messy, so I did not figure out how to extract channels properly.

This code, for the first audio track, works fine:

```
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.1.0 "eng channel 1.wav"
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.1.1 "eng channel 2.wav"
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.1.2 "eng channel 3.wav"
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.1.3 "eng channel 4.wav"
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.1.4 "eng channel 5.wav"
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.1.5 "eng channel 6.wav"
```

I believe that **0.1.0** is: input #0 (movie.mkv); then stream 1 (audio eng); then channel 0 (very first channel).

But when I'm trying to extract channels from second audio track...

```
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.2.0 "ger channel 1.wav"
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.2.1 "ger channel 2.wav"
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.2.2 "ger channel 3.wav"
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.2.3 "ger channel 4.wav"
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.2.4 "ger channel 5.wav"
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.2.5 "ger channel 6.wav"
```

...it extracts not German sound, but instead it results with the same eng channels (which also sound little louder than in previous case). In this code, **0.2.0** appears to be: input #0 (movie.mkv); then stream 2 (audio ger); then channel 0 (very first channel).

So what am I doing wrong? :-)

Comment: I provided an answer that give an alternative solution. If you still want to use `-map_channel` then show the complete log from `ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map_channel 0.2.0 "ger channel 1.wav"`

Comment: No, it's not necessary, channelsplit is just fine :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use the channelsplit filter

[image: diagram of splitting 5.1 channel layout to individual mono components]

The [channelsplit filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelsplit) is easier:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:a:0]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1(side)[FL][FR][FC][LFE][SL][SR]" -map "[FL]" front_left.wav -map "[FR]" front_right.wav -map "[FC]" front_center.wav -map "[LFE]" lfe.wav -map "[SL]" side_left.wav -map "[SR]" side_right.wav
```

- The above example will get audio from the first audio stream (`Stream #0:1(eng)`). If you want `Stream #0:2(ger)` then change `[0:a:0]` to `[0:a:1]`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12943003/) for more details on the `[0:a:0]` syntax.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channels](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) for more examples.
- See `ffmpeg -layouts` for a list of channel layouts and channel names which is helpful when using channelsplit.

Comment: I assumed somebody would suggest using filter_complex and channelsplit. I think that using channelsplit really makes the command more readable. Thank you so much for explaining!