# ffmpeg: 1 audio file + js animation = 1 mp4 video

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, video-capture, h.264

I would like to make an mp4 file from 1 audio file and some java script animations produced on a browser ?! How is that possible please?
Any working example or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first solution**

Use a software to capture your screen (like quicktime, camtasia, ...) and create a composition with ffmpeg ([How to add a new audio (not mixing) into a video using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/ffmpeg-how-to-add-new-audio-not-mixing-in-video))

**Second solution**

if you want to automate the recording, use CasperJS (casperjs.org) to take multiple screenshots like that

```
[...]

var count       = 0,
        max         = 10,
        delay       = 500,
        self        = this;

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        self.wait(delay, function() {

            self.captureSelector('temp-' + count + '.png', "html");

            count++;

        });
    }

[...]
```

CasperJS create a frameset, you have just to create a video from this frameset :

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i temp-%d.png -r 10 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 15000k your_movie.mp4
```

And after, add the song ([How to add a new audio (not mixing) into a video using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/ffmpeg-how-to-add-new-audio-not-mixing-in-video))

Comment: Thank you Anthony. Your second solution is great and is what I was looking for. And it seems to be the one that can do the job for me without needing to use a server side!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a video capture tool (quicktime, vlc, etc.) to get the animation and then add in the audio afterwards. If you'd like to this programmatically you can do something like [this](http://www.ultramegatech.com/2010/09/record-html-canvas-animations-to-video/).

Comment: Thank you G- . your second solution is close to what I am looking for but since it does need to upload the images and then download them, I would prefer not to use it.