# How to create a video with raw images (.rgb format) and add audio to it in python?

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, avconv

I have been trying with openCV but it doesn't seem to help much. Also, I have tried ffmpeg and avconv. But I think am making a mistake somewhere. Could someone please guide me?

Comment: How can anyone provide help when you did not include any of your code and any of the actual errors you may be encountering?

Answer (score 6):

Try with MoviePy:

```
import moviepy.editor as mpy
clip = mpy.ImageSequenceClip("some/folder/with/images", fps=10)
audio = (mpy.AudioFileClip("some_audio_file.mp3") # or any other format
            .set_duration(clip.duration))
clip.audio = audio
clip.write_videofile("my_video.mp4") # or any other format
```

Comment: +1 for this quick workaround. However, setting audio throws this error: `OSError: Error in file,  Accessing time t=6.42-6.47 seconds, with clip duration=6 seconds`

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is useful for image processing and computational imaging. What you need is just ffmpeg.

1. For creating video from still images read this: [Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)
2. For adding audio to video: [ffmpeg, how to add new audio (not mixing) in video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/ffmpeg-how-to-add-new-audio-not-mixing-in-video)