# Can not hear audio when concatenate some mp4 files using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to concatenate some MP4 files. Only one of them has audio. The other ones hasn't.

MyList.txt contains:
file1.mp4 without audio and 5s length
File2.mp4 without audio and 5s length
File3.mp4 without audio and 5s length
File4.mp4 with audio and Ns length

I need an output that cotains the 4 mp4 files and when file4.mp4 starts I want to hear its audio.

If I set the file4.mp4 as the first video to concat, the output video has audio, but If I set the file4.mp4 in another position, the output video hasn't audio.

What I'm doing wrong? What I have to modify in my code?

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i myList.txt -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating a silent track for your mp4 files without any sound and then concatenating them?

ffmpeg -i "clip.mp4" -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -shortest -y "new_clip.mp4"

This does the following:

- Take clip.mp4 (which is the video clip without audio) (-i "clip.mp4")
- Generate the minimum silence required (-f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0
  -shortest)
- Output the result (-y "new_clip.mp4")

Same problem but asked on stack exchange:
[Link](https://superuser.com/questions/1096921/concatenating-videos-with-ffmpeg-produces-silent-video-when-the-first-video-has)

Broader explanation can be found here:
[second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/how-to-add-a-new-audio-not-mixing-into-a-video-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: Recommend adding `-c:v copy` output option to avoid re-encoding the video.