# add background music to video using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video file (mp4) with sound, how can I add background music to it? Using ffmpeg.

Example please :)
I tried like this:

```
ffmpeg -i son.wav -i video_origine.mp4 video_finale.mp4
```

But this method muffles the main sound.

Comment: Show the full log from the command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a new audio (not mixing) into a video using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/how-to-add-a-new-audio-not-mixing-into-a-video-using-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this link if it will be helpfull and it have detailed information so please read it carefully:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783474/10752962