# How to edit mp4 audio with Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mp3, mp4

For a project at work we use this https://pub.dev/packages/tapioca package in a flutter app, the goal of this app is to make a simple video editing app with Flutter.

Current possibilities; Adding images/text to a video, cut the video and show a preview.

The only thing I can't seem to figure out is audio editing, possibility to remove the original audio and put another audio file over the video. Does anybody know how this would be possible to do?

Thanks in advance,
Greetz

Comment: Couldn't find a quick exact match for the requirement but check [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) package.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I looked into it and it seems that FFMPEG for flutter might work. If there are any other solutions I still would like to hear them

Comment: I was able to do this and the already mentioned features + way more with flutter_ffmpeg. If anybody has a questions about flutter_ffmpeg then consider asking them, I recommend to look at the original ffmpeg documentation as the flutter documentation for ffmpeg is very limited.

Comment: Hi I want to integrate same functionality, like removing sound and integrating custom one. Kindly can you guide me

Comment: I'd recommend looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/how-to-add-a-new-audio-not-mixing-into-a-video-using-ffmpeg

Together with it's official documentation: https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

Most of these command will work for the FFMPEG mobile equivalent.